# Spring boot project not reloading data from database

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, maven

i have been working on a full stack application using angular and spring boot for the first time (i'm following a full project tutorial),

i downloaded a project from https://start.spring.io/ and added the following dependencies; mySQL driver , lombok, spring data JPA and REST repositories .after working on my project and executing it ,i found out that the data are not loaded from the database (PS: database not empty)    :[and here's my execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XejiO.png)

: [while this is the tutor's result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRoZ4.png)

i ingore it and tried to consume the data in the front end using angular [and this is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA53K.png)

[while this is my tutor's results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRvT5.png)

i'll share with you my application propreties here :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/full-stack-ecommerce?useSSL=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=ecommerceapp
spring.datasource.password=ecommerceapp

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

spring.data.rest.base-path=/api

server.port=9091
```

and my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.luv2code</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-ecommerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-ecommerce</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Ecommerce Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> 
                     
</dependency>
<dependency> 
                      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
                      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> 
                      </dependency>
<dependency> 
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId> 
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId> 
                        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i truly appreciate any help

Comment: Might have to to see the complete tutorial, you are compiling with java version 17 ? Sure the dependencies and everything is compatible ?

Comment: You tried browser debug ?

Comment: @AchillesVan yes i tried,, there are not a single error in the whole project and still not running correctly

Comment: @Harsh can version incompatibility  be a problem ? how do i know the what versions are compatible ?

Comment: Can you show us the product and controller class in java? Are you using getters (via lombok)?

Answer (score 0):

Im doing exactly the same Chad project now, everything works, Java 17 and spring 2.6.1

here is application properties (i changed username, password):

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/full-stack-ecommerce?useSSL=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=angfullecom
spring.datasource.password=angfullecom

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

As you see i dont have your line: server.port=9091

my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ilze</groupId>
    <artifactId>full-ang-ecommerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>full-ang-ecommerce</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Angular Ecommerce Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Did you accessed the project using address http://localhost:8080/api/products ?

Comment: i used server.port=9091 to change the port number because the port 8080 won't work, and yes i accesed it using that address but with the port 9091 like this : http://localhost:9091/api/products

Comment: Trying to think what might cause it .. you tried inspect in console? Maybe some error there. I would also refresh the maven button.

Comment: yes i tried inspecting the console but it's all good no errors showed up